# OpenCV inRange not finding any color

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

Hello Im writing a program which can detect playing cards. One of the card's attributes is his color.
I'm trying to run inRange with the three colors possible and detect which color it is based on the amount of white pixels inRange returns.
The color with the most white pixels is probably the color of the card.

The problem: inRange returns a full black mat. not finding any of the colors.

The method for finding the card's color.

```
public String matchCardColor(Mat wrap){
        //The Mat format is bgr so we convert it to hsv to better find the colors.
        Mat hsv = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(wrap,hsv,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV,0);

        //Defining the colors boundaries.
        Boundaries[] colors = {new Boundaries(Card.Color.GREEN),
                new Boundaries(Card.Color.PURPLE),
                new Boundaries(Card.Color.RED)};

        //Finding the color with the most pixels found.
        Mat coloredPixels = new Mat();
        Mat mask = new Mat();
        int foundPixels;
        int maxPixels = 0;
        String color = "N/A";

        for (Boundaries b :
                colors) {
            Core.inRange(hsv,b.getLowerBoundary(),b.getUpperBoundary(),coloredPixels);
            foundPixels = getWhitePixles(coloredPixels);
            if (foundPixels>maxPixels){
                maxPixels = foundPixels;
                color = b.getColor();
                mask = coloredPixels.clone();
            }
        }
        //mainImgView.setImage(mat2Image(mask));
        System.out.println("Max pixels found: " + maxPixels);
        return color;
    }
```

Boundaries is a class made to describe a color's boundaries.

```
public class Boundaries {
    private Scalar lowerBoundary, upperBoundary;
    private String name;

public Boundaries(String name){
        this.name = name;
        switch (name){
            case Card.Color.GREEN: lowerBoundary = new Scalar(50,100,20);
                upperBoundary = new Scalar(70,255,255);
                break;
            case Card.Color.PURPLE: lowerBoundary = new Scalar(140,100,20);
                upperBoundary = new Scalar(160,255,255);
                break;
            case Card.Color.RED: lowerBoundary = new Scalar(170,100,20);
                upperBoundary = new Scalar(10,255,255);
                break;
            default: name = "Wrong color name entered!";
                break;
        }
    }
    public String getColor(){
        return name;
    }
    public Scalar getLowerBoundary(){
        return lowerBoundary;
    }
    public Scalar getUpperBoundary(){
        return upperBoundary;
    }
}
```

getWhitePixels just counts the number of pixels with 255 value.

```
private int getWhitePixles(Mat mat) {
        int whitePixels = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<mat.size().height; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<mat.size().width; j++)
                if (mat.get(i,j)[0]==255)
                    whitePixels++;
        return whitePixels;
    }
```

The Mat I'm testing:
[Wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGtfc.jpg)

The coloredPixels stays a full black Mat through every iteration and maxPixels stays 0, even though the card has Red in it.

EDIT: I gave the colors the wrong hsv boundaries. Shold've double checked myself. After changing the values it works!

Comment: For your RED colour boundaries, you're asking for hue that's greater than 170 and less than 10 at the same time. There are obviously no values for which that can be true.

Comment: @DanMašek Danm i feel so stupid. I gave both purple and red the wrong values :(

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this issue on android, I found that an image from a camera requires the v3 parameter of the `Scalar` to be set. That is:

```java
case Card.Color.GREEN: lowerBoundary = new Scalar(50,100,20);
    upperBoundary = new Scalar(70,255,255);
    break;
```

becomes

```java
case Card.Color.GREEN: lowerBoundary = new Scalar(50,100,20,0);
    upperBoundary = new Scalar(70,255,255,255);
    break;
```

Notice this uses a different constructor to cover the full range of alpha values (I am pretty sure v3 refers to alpha if all values are specified)

Hope this helps :)